# Porting a Blender game to another engine

Tags: java, blender

I'm planning to make a 3D, interactive main menu in Blender for a visual novel I'm making. The coders are writing their own engine. I'm wondering if it's possible to make the main menu in Blender and then put it into the custom engine. The engine is being written in Java.

Sorry, if I'm vague. I propsed the idea, but don't know much about coding (I'm an artist).

Comment: Show us some code which you tried!!!

Comment: So much would rely on how the engine works...

Comment: As you are not a programmer it will be a non-trivial task for you. If this code has been written on java, and source code is available, then it can be changed. Just ask a professional programmer to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. However that shouldn't stop you from prototyping it in Blender. If your own engine is not ready yet and you wish to contribute to this menu, Blender would let you get the idea down in a functional way. However, it is likely that your engine will not have the exact same API as the BGE. The most you could do is copy down the logic that went into the making of your menu (kind of like how pseudo code works). Just remember that the BGE uses python and that yours could be something else.